# How to check unique validation while update in yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I am working in yii2 project. I have user model in that email id should be unique. In add function it is working. But when i update record it is not checking unique validation.

Following is my user model code :

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'mobile', 'email', 'password_hash', 'role_id'], 'required'],
            [['address'], 'string'],
            [['role_id'], 'integer'],
            [['email'], 'email'],
            [['email'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['email']],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password_hash'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['mobile'], 'required','on'=>'create,update'],
            //[['mobile'], 'string','max'=>10],
            [['mobile'], 'number','numberPattern' => '/^[0-9]{10}$/','message'=>"Mobile must be integer and should not greater then 10 digit"],
            [['password_hash'],'string','min'=>6],
            //[['mobile'], 'number'],
            [['status'], 'string', 'max' => 1,'on'=>'create,update'],
            [['role_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Roles::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['role_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
```

> Even I tried : [['email'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' =>
>   ['email'], 'on'=>array('create','update')],

But nothing happen it is not checking unique rule in update function.

Comment: You don't have to add `targetAttribute` if it's the same as checked one. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: Yes I removed still it is not working in update page

Comment: Again - why do you think it's not working? Explain what do you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: Right now if I enter any existing email id while update any record it is inserting. But it should return validation message that "email id already been taken"

Comment: By "any existing" you mean different from the one you try to update?

Comment: I am updating with same email id which is already exist in database with different user.

for example UserA has email id user@gmail.com and I am updating UserB's email id with user@gmail.com then it should return validation message the this email id already exist.

Comment: This looks like problem somewhere else. Post your controller's action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the column for check is the same try using

```
[['email'], 'unique'],
```

Answer (score 0):

TargetClass check existing email in DB with help model User

```
   ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
    ['email', 'required'],
    ['email', 'email'],
    ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\app\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],
```

Comment: Thanks bro but this is not working while update records.\